# Jquery Observer Pattern for Notification System

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, observer-pattern

I have been doing some research for a notification system. In my project, people can post some questions with a category id. Lets say, another user wants to follow that category's all questions. Therefore, If I follow that category, I want to get notified for all those questions instantly.

I dont want to do scheduled job to check DB for every minute for a new question, I want to get notified when a new question is inserted.

How can I do that?

Comment: you want to get notified - but don't want to check if you were notified

Comment: Websockets. See: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: I dont want to do unnecessary Selects to DB

Comment: Sounds like SignalR is the tool you're looking for.